# Distributed Marketing Email Template Not Visible in Quick Send menu (DM Admin CRM)

Tags: marketing-cloud, error-messages, distributed-marketing

I am trying to enable a Journey template for Distributed Marketing (Quick Send) but after I activate the journey, I am unable to see that journey in the journey list in the Distributed Marketing Admin App (CRM) --> Administration --> Quick Send Journeys --> 'Available Journey list'

Has anyone else experienced this before, I've tried to troubleshoot by: changing DEs, ensuring reentry options, and checked permissions. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer! Journeys for DM can only have a single message not multiple, but multiple activities are possible.